# Make the footnote in a table at the bottom of current page

Tags: tables, footnotes

Finally, I add footnote in a table. But it does not locate in the bottom of the page. It is below the table. And, \usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} does not work in my case. How could I make the footnote at the bottom of the page.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} 
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccccc}
\toprule
1   &   2\footnote{I am a footnote. But I am in wrong place.}   \\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Remember, that the footnote has to be moved with the floating environment (table) to another page if there is the need.

Comment: @Johannes_B an `H` table isn't a float.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle O right, but then again, `H` isn't a good idea (IMHO).

Comment: @Johannes_B it's a bad idea (and it's my idea:-)

Answer (score 6):

Please *always* include a complete small document not just a fragment. Within a minpage footnotes are for that *mini* page and come at the bottom of there. That is the only function minipage is serving there.

Get rid of `\begin{table}[H]` and `\begin{minipage}`  and just have the `\tabularx` then the footnote will work as intended,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need the caption. So I cannot get rid of table

Comment: @Vivian If you had posted an example with a caption I would have mentioned the (one line) `capt-of` package which would allow you to use `\captionof{table}{my caption}`

Comment: You also have the `tablefootnote` package: it is intended to work in case the `\footnotemark/\footnotetext`pair doesn't, and it cooperates with `hyperref`.